# How do electrons stay in orbitals in Bohmian Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbital-motion, stability, bohmian-mechanics

I've been reading various realist interpretations of quantum mechanics and in Bohmian Mechanics, I found that the "wave" aspect of a quantum particle is removed from the particle to preserve the particle's *particle* character. Now this leads me to a very basic question about problems that quantum mechanics intended to solve in the first place.

When Bohr quantized the atomic orbitals, he did so in hopes of modelling a stable orbital that doesn't decay: imagining a standing wave that doesn't radiate EM waves. However, in BM, it is the guiding wave that assumes the shape of the orbitals and electrons are supposed to stay inside it, without moving, with all their kinetic energy stored in the quantum potential.

How does BM explain an electron without any motion? Even in the realist picture, imagining a electron trajectory as simply at rest w.r.t the nucleus, not even budging, sounds anything but sensible to me. If however electrons do move inside orbitals, such as *2p*, then we should not expect to see higher elements in nature.

Is there something I'm not understanding with this picture or is the electron stationary?